# cts:collection-match() with a more complex pattern?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I currently have collection names with various patterns. In one of these patterns, the collection name ends in a date string, like **2017-02-28**. IS there any way to use `cts:collection-match()` or something else to select only the collection names that end in this format, i.e. `\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cts:collection-match` does not take a regex unfortunately. The closest you can get with just that function is:

```
cts:collection-match("*-????-??-??")
```

You can use XPath to trim it down further:

```
cts:collection-match("*-????-??-??")[matches(., "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$")]
```

HTH!